# irlba not installing on Mac OS

Tags: r, macos, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I cannot seem to get the `irlba` R package to install on my mac system.

After running `install.packages("irlba", force = TRUE, type = "source")`, I get the following error

```
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 233555 bytes (228 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 228 KB

* installing *source* package ‘irlba’ ...
** package ‘irlba’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c irlb.c -o irlb.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/Matrix/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c utility.c -o utility.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o irlba.so irlb.o utility.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [irlba.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘irlba’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/irlba’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘irlba’ had non-zero exit status
```

What does the `...had a non-zero exit status` warning tag mean? and how can I resolve that?

I would appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a FORTRAN compiler on macOS which is common and well-known. CRAN maintains a dedicated section on how to work around that, see and carefully read:

https://mac.r-project.org/tools/